# How to use the percentage of matches to decide if two characters match in R

Tags: r, matching, stringr, grepl, fuzzy

### Context

I have two vectors. `fruits_Jack_eat` is a vector of `length=1` that stores the fruits Jack ate. `fruits_list` is a vector of `length=3` that stores different types of fruits.

### Question

I want to find out if Jack ate 1 or more fruits in the `fruits_list`. But the situation is not that simple. `fruits_list[1]` is `'Navel orange'`. one of the fruits Jack ate is `XXXorange`. although `XXXorange` is not exactly the same as `Navel orange`, I still think the situation is a match.

### Reproducible code

```
fruits_Jack_eat = 'XXXorange,PPPapple,QQQbanana'
  
fruits_list = c('Navel orange', 'Super big apple', 'Very yellow banana')
```

### Expect output

When I enter `fruits_Jack_eat` and `fruits_list`, the result should return a dataframe. The first column is a `logical` vector that indicates whether or not the match is on. The second column is a `character` vector indicating the characters in `fruits_Jack_eat` that are similar to `fruits_list`. Maybe like this:

```
df_output = data.frame(matched = TRUE, matched_char = c('orange,apple,banana'))

> df_output
  matched        matched_char
1    TRUE orange,apple,banana
```

### What I've done

1. [how to get percentage character match between two strings using sqldf in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917858/how-to-get-percentage-character-match-between-two-strings-using-sqldf-in-r)
2. [Identify the percentage of string Match in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763651/identify-the-percentage-of-string-match-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
 matched_char <- str_extract(fruits_list, 
    str_replace_all(str_remove_all(fruits_Jack_eat, "[A-Z]+"), ",", "|"))
tibble(matched = any(length(matched_char) > 0),
     matched_char = str_c(matched_char, collapse = ","))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  matched matched_char       
  <lgl>   <chr>              
1 TRUE    orange,apple,banana
```